# Можно ли создать динамический массив, не зная его длину в С++?

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Можно ли создать динамический массив не зная его длину? Вот ссылка на задачу(взята с задачника по питону) - https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/lists/problems/even_indices/
В ней не указывается длина массива, как ее можно решить?

Comment: Например, использовать `vector`. Только из условия непонятно, нужен ли там массив вообще. Я так понял, это строка входных данных? тогда просто читать и выводить каждое второе значение...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам правильно пишут, что массив создавать не нужно, и можно сразу обрабатывать числа.

Но если хочется массив, то так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> list;
    int elem;
    while (std::cin >> elem)
        list.push_back(elem); // Вот тут вместо вставки в массив можно сразу печатать.

    // Как пропускать каждое второе число - сами разберетесь.
    for (int x : list)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Или, более выпендрежное решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> list(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {});

    for (int x : list)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Оба варианта считывают до конца файла. Если хочется остановиться в конце строки, то так:

```
// #include <sstream>

std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream ss(line);

// Дальше берете одно из двух решений выше, и меняете там `std::cin` на `ss`.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, именно это я и хотел узнать

Answer (score 1):

у меня такая же задача на c++ с сириуса
вот как я ее решил:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> v[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i += 2)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

вектор это массив не имеющий границ, можешь задать, можешь и не задавать.
в оригинальной задаче вводилось число, показывающее количество элементов в массиве.
он идет от 0 элемента до n-1, а не как обычный от 1 до n.
Ответ на твой вопрос: "Можно ли создать динамический массив не зная его длину?" - да создать можно, да только программа не знает, когда остановиться, поэтому ей нужен стоп сигнал (грубо говоря), то, что будет завершать ввод чисел в бесконечный массив, называющийся вектор. в моем случае ввод завершается, когда ввели n элементов.

Comment: Не компилируется. Если исправить опечатку - падает с ошибкой при вводе первого элемента.

Comment: исправлю, только теперь комментариев не будет

Comment: сразу минус блин поставил, а я мучался, расписывал

Comment: Теперь работает. Но автор просит без указания длины... На будущее, тут как-то не принято просить репутацию. Лучше вместо этого поправить форматирование в ответе - большие буквы в начале предложений, разделить на абзацы - толку больше будет.

Comment: но я хочу репутацию, чтобы оценивать чужие ответы и др. Во вторых, невозможно без указания длины его отсортировать- ввод в массив не закончен.  можно и без ввода длины, только мы должны знать, когда ввод в массив завершать. например, если стоит ноль в конце, мы завершаем ввод. или мы знаем, сколько у нас значений вводится, например- 5 штук, тогда делаем ввод в массив циклом, повторяя ввод 5 раз. Язык- такая штука, в которой сначала одно заканчивается, как здесь ввод в массив, а потом другое начинается, здесь - вывод ячеек с четным номером

Comment: нам на самом деле не надо знать размеры массива, нам нужно знать, когда закончить ввод значений

Comment: А почему не просто выводить требуемые значения, не записывая их в вектор? Как намекал @Harry?

Comment: Не понятно ваше недовольство. По условию задачи первое число во входных данных — это вовсе не количество элементов во входной последовательности чисел, а просто первый элемент этой последовательности. Ваше решение ошибочно.

Comment: *"нам на самом деле не надо знать размеры массива, нам нужно знать, когда закончить ввод значений"* Вот это вот хорошо бы показать кодом в ответе. *"но я хочу репутацию"* Вы ее быстрее получите, если не будете просить в лоб. Лучше пишите хорошие ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть `vector` и `string`, но в этой задаче они вообще не нужны:

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##JYzRaoQwFETf8xXTLd2NbAPGJCZi7Zf0RaLuCm1Wo4JQ@u326j6EzFzOGT8M4ub9tr32wX8vTYsPP81N//hkrA8zfuo@8IT9MmCva8kodY8IvoSpv4W2wVilJSZfh46f3prTO85rgqqCLHG9jgnx5HbgL3w8y@TZgSHS3mGAlDU5hodl9vc68stXuDwvsZ2XGJCW7G/bhM6hDGwGYQsoB6EySGQKwunjmRQ7JIylX@@kUigkRA7njiB3mQhL1SBX0AZGQyoY2pM0m0JTKhyURWH/AQ)

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  int x;

  for (unsigned q=0; scanf("%d", &x) == 1; ++q)
    if (!(q&1))
      printf("%d ", x);

  putchar('\n');

  return 0;
}
```